# How can I reshape my solutions to make a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I need some help on the following. I need to run `Solve` for multiple values of a and b. To do so instead of using `Do`, I use `Table`. I get the set of solutions shown below. It is a set of {a, b, x} where x can take multiple values. Now I need to 3D plot of these solutions. I can see how to do this in matlab structure, if I had the solutions in a column vector. So basically I just need to pull out those solutions so that I have the parameter a in the first cell, the parameter b in the second cell, and x in the third cell. Or maybe there's an easier way. I just need to plot all solutions in a 3D plot. How do I do it?

```
 eq = K*x^gamma*(1 - 2*(1 + B^2)*x)^ki - T;

 Abar = (a/b)^(1/2);

 B = (2*(Abar - 1) + (4*Abar^2 + Abar + 4)^(1/2))/(3*(Abar)^(1/2));

 T = a*(1 + 3/(4*B*Abar));

 K = (B*(2*a)^(1/2) + (2*b)^(1/2))^(2*gamma);

 solutions = 
  Table[
    Flatten[N[{a, b, x /. 
      Solve[eq == 0 && 0 < x < 1 && 2*(x + B^2*x) <= 1, x]}]], 
    {a, 1, 5, 1}, {b, 1, 5, 1}];
```

> ```
> {
>   {{1., 1., x}, {1., 2., 0.132143, 0.294483}, 
>    {1., 3., 0.105496, 0.331848}, {1., 4., 0.0886402, 0.353948}, 
>    {1., 5., 0.0767417, 0.369095}},
>   {{2., 1., 0.0855558, 0.185235}, {2., 2., 0.0794541, 0.246061}, 
>    {2., 3., 0.071315, 0.281353}, {2., 4., 0.0641548, 0.305209}, 
>    {2., 5., 0.0581704, 0.322734}},
>   {{3., 1., 0.0529289, 0.160339}, {3., 2., 0.0551478, 0.214722}, 
>    {3., 3., 0.0528107, 0.248876}, {3., 4., 0.0496061, 0.273123}, 
>    {3., 5., 0.0464105, 0.291539}},
>   {{4., 1., 0.037211, 0.142182}, {4., 2., 0.0413613, 0.19255}, 
>    {4., 3.,0.041316, 0.22547}, {4., 4., 0.0400016, 0.24953}, 
>    {4., 5., 0.0382946, 0.268203}},
>   {{5., 1., 0.0281069, 0.128705}, {5., 2., 0.0325974, 0.175866}, 
>    {5., 3., 0.0335523, 0.207523}, {5., 4., 0.0332253, 0.231138}, 
>    {5., 5., 0.032375, 0.24976}}
> }
> ```

Comment: This wouldn't be very difficult if your first data point had the same form as the others rather than being `{1., 1., l2}`. Why isn't this point a numeric 4-vector like the others?

Comment: it is because in some range of values a and b, there-s no solution. in some range instead there will be a unique solution. in other 2 solutions. thanks for helping

Comment: You need to split out `a,b` with each of the multiple solutions, something like `{a,b,x}/.Solve..`

Comment: and after splitting them,  how do I plot them in 3d? thank you a lot

Comment: maybe `ListPointPlot3D`   ( a working example would help here )

Comment: when I do {a,b,x} the solutions cluster in one as {{{1., 1., l2}, {1., 2., 0.132143, 1., 2., 0.294483}, {1., 3., 
   0.105496, 1., 3., 0.331848},

Comment: If you could give us `eq` it would be helpful.

Comment: I added it thanks

Comment: need values for all the constants too..

Comment: they are functions of a and b. i added them. any suggestions? thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to guess at `ki` and `gamma` :

```
 ki = 1
 gamma = 3
 Abar = (a/b)^(1/2);
 B = (2*(Abar - 1) + (4*Abar^2 + Abar + 4)^(1/2))/(3*(Abar)^(1/2));
 T = a*(1 + 3/(4*B*Abar));
 K = (B*(2*a)^(1/2) + (2*b)^(1/2))^(2*gamma);
 eq = K*x^gamma*(1 - 2*(1 + B^2)*x)^ki - T
 solutions = 
  Flatten[Table[{a, b, N[x /. #]} & /@ 
     Solve[eq == 0 && 0 < x < 1 && 2*(x + B^2*x) <= 1, x],
      {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}], 2]
 ListPointPlot3D[solutions]
```

[image]